Make one param type depend on another in function in typescript
enum FilterType {
    userId = 'userId',
    date = 'date',
    section ='section'
}

type FilterValueType = {
    [FilterType.userId]: string;
    [FilterType.date]: Date;
    [FilterType.section]: number;
};

const filters = {} as FilterValueType

function setFilter<T extends FilterType>(type: T, value: FilterValueType[T] ) {
    if (type === FilterType.userId) {
        filters.userId = value
    }
    if (type === FilterType.date) {
        filters.date = value
    }
    if (type === FilterType.section) {
        filters.section = value
    }
}

I have come snipped above, I need function know value type depend on type param . Typescript shows me Type 'string | number | Date' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
